# After inserting a column into dataframe using Pandas, the first element of the inserted column is deleted

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataframe and am trying to add a leading (far left, 0th position) column for descriptive purposes. The dataframe and column which I'm trying to insert both have the same number of lines.

The column I'm inserting looks like this:

```
Description 1
Description 2
Description 3
.
.
.
Description n
```

The code I'm using to attach the column is:

`df.insert(loc=0, column='description', value=columnToInsert)`

The code I'm using to write to file is:

`df.to_csv('output', sep='\t', header=None, index=None)`

(Note: I've written to file with and without the "header=None" option, doesn't change my problem)

Now after writing to file, what I end up getting is:

```
Description 2    E11    ...    E1n
Description 3    E21    ...    E2n
.
.
.
Description n    E(n-1)1...    E(n-1)n
          NaN    En1    ...    Enn
```

So the first element of my descriptive, leading column is deleted, all the descriptions are off by one, and the last row has "not a number" as it's description.

I have no idea what I'm doing which might cause this, and I'm not really sure where to start in correcting it.

Comment: could it be that the first row of the description is treated as a column header?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The issue was stemming from the fact that I had deleted a row from my large dataframe prior to inserting my descriptive column, this was causing the indices to line up improperly.

So now I included the line:

`df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)`

Everything lines up properly now and no elements are deleted!